# OpAmp as Differential Amplifier Equation

Tags: operational-amplifier, math

I am currently reading a (german) textbook about Operational Amplifiers. In the Chapter about the use as an differential amplifier, the authors derive the equation for the output voltage (for the case that two resistors are equal).
I understand how they derive the equation until the last step. They somehow condense the equation but I dont know how. Can someone explain it to me step by step?

[image: Schematic note that each two have the same value]

[image: Derivation]

Comment: Can you be precise about what step you don't understand - put a red circle around it if that's easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you mean this little bit: -

[image]

Comment: Yes that was exactly the part I meant. Sometimes its difficult for me to simplify equations and find out how to start. But now I understand how you got the final equation. Thanks a lot for your help.